# How to prevent two API calls in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular, how to prevent two API calls?
I call a function two times in `ngOninit`, one should only call when id changes from URL parameter. While loading the page for the first time itself both functions get invoked.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getCategoryList();
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log("categoryChange");
    this.categoryId = params['cat'] || '';
    if (this.categoryId) {
      this.getCategoryList();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is getCategoryList() depends on categoryId?

Comment: yes,  getCategoryList() depends on categoryId

Comment: the call within the `subscribe` is not detecting change but rather if the `params['cat']` is truthy.

Comment: What categoryId value you sends when categoryId in not in url param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`distinct()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinct) to filter distict values.

```
this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params['cat']), distinct())
.subscribe(cat => {
    console.log(cat);
});
```

Or use [`debounce()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) to avoid frequent calls

```
this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params['cat']), debounceTime(100))
.subscribe(cat => {
    console.log(cat);
});
```

Or you can just compare the previous value and avoid calling API if it's the same.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log("categoryChange");
  const categoryId = params['cat'] || '';
  if (this.categoryId !== categoryId && categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.getCategoryList();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If route param is available it will assign categoryId else null will be used. You can assign any default value instead of null if cat param is unavailable.

This makes sure you will have only one API call if route param is available or not.

Remove this.getCategoryList() call onOnit. So final code will be

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      map(param => param['cat'] || null)
    ).subscribe(categoryId => {
      this.categoryId = categoryId;
      this.getCategoryList();
    });
  }
```